# How to avoid "xargs genstrings" across multiple directories from generating duplicated keys?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using this command to generate Localizable.strings file. I have to go through multiple directories so use this command ...

`find ./ -name *.m | xargs genstrings -o en.lproj`

to do the job. It works but gives duplicate keys if the files are in different directories. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, it was just because I made a typo on one of the duplicated entries, like  "ํFather" and "Father" (notice the left quotes). So it seems like genstrings is really smart enough to merge the results even in different directories. As I'm curious it can detect duplicate in files, so why don't they check on directories as well. :P